# How is Soundflower an Output Audio Device?

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, imac

I understand Soundflower to be a tool to capture computer system audio, and thus setting up as an input makes sense (or as an Aggregate Device) in Audio Midi Setup.

But then...

**Q1)** Why is *Soundflower (2ch)* an Output choice in System Preferences > Sound menu?

**Q2)** Why do many Soundflower tutorials recommend creating a Multi-Output Device and adding *Soundflower (2ch)* along side *Built-in Output*?

**Q3)** When using Soundflower, why is it even a choice to choose in a Multi-Output Device?

This make no sense to me, as I understand Soundflower to be an input only, like a microphone.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: As mentioned in [ReadMe](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/blob/master/Installer/ReadMe.rtf) : _To send the output of one application to another, simply select
Soundflower as the output device within the first application
and Soundflower as the input device within the second
application._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soundflower is used to *Route audio from one application to another*. Soundflower itself can't capture audio, only route signals.

For routing you need at least 1 **input** and 1 **output**. So say you want to route the sound from DAW1 to DAW2. You select Soundflower **input** in DAW1 as **output** and Soundflower **output** as **input** in DAW2.

Most people use Soundflower for recording audio during a screencast. Then you want to make a combination of the *Built-in Output* and the *Soundflower input*. This way you can send the audio to your recording software via Soundflower while still listening to the sound from the *Built-in Output*

Comment: Ah yes, it wasn't immediately clear that Soundflower acts like a pipe for any audio sources.  It's job is not to necessarily capture computer audio like I had originally thought.